# What is the probability of an XX female or XY male?

Tags: genetics, homework, human-genetics

**Homework question**

> In genetics the chance of having a male or female is 50% for male and 50% for female. Using factorial method and Punnett Square prove or disprove the claim.

**My answer**

Using the factorial method:

```
P        XY  * XX

F1     XX  XX  XY  XY
```

Punnett Square method:

```
+-----+----+
| XX  | XY |
+-----+----+
| XX  | XY |
+-----+----+
```

So yes, the claim is right 50% for male and 50% for female.

**I want to make sure that I solved the problem correctly using the two methods (factorial and Punnett).**

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: It is funny that some may see two different methods here. But yes, it looks good to me too.